# Defining a function in Ubuntu

Tags: functions

I am using Ubuntu to access a remote computer where I am doing calculations. I can access information about previously run jobs using the command

```
sacct --starttime 2022-09-17 --format=JobID,Jobname,state,start,end,elapsed,ncpus,nodelist
```

I would like to create a function 'history' that takes a date (in the above example 2022-09-17) and executes the above code with that date as starttime. I do not have experience with any coding in Ubuntu, so it would be great if someone can tell me how I can define such a function.

**Edit**: I found the solution:

```
function history { sacct --starttime $1 --format=JobID,Jobname,state,start,end,elapsed,ncpus,nodelist; }
```

Comment: You can write a script. It is simple. Where do you want to get a date from? Enter it manually or take the current date?

Comment: Research Bash scripting. You can do many useful things.

Comment: I would like to enter it manually. For example 'history 2022-09-17'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, please don't name your function `history`. That is the name for bash's history tool which allows you to see and manipulate the history of commands you have run. So if you define a new function with the same name, you will lose the original. So call yours something like `hist` or anything else not taken.

Next, the format for shell functions is:

```
function_name(){ command1; command2; ... commandN; }
```

In some shells, including `bash`, the default on Ubuntu, you can also add the optional keyword `function` at the beginning:

```
function function_name(){ command1; command2; ... commandN; }
```

But that isn't needed. So, in your case, you would do something like this:

```
hist() { sacct --starttime "$1" --format=JobID,Jobname,state,start,end,elapsed,ncpus,nodelist; }
```

Note how I quoted the `"$1"`. This is important as it protects the value you pass from the shell, so any special characters aren't expanded. For more details on why quoting is important, see:

- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/22222)
- [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/22222)

Finally, to make the function available to all new shells you open, edit the file `~/.bashrc` and add the lines above to it. Now, the next time you open a new terminal, the function will be available to you.

Comment: Great answer, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Create a script `hist.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
sacct --starttime $1 --format=JobID,Jobname,state,start,end,elapsed,ncpus,nodelist
```

Give it execution permission by

```
chmod +x hist.sh
```

Run it by

```
./hist.sh 2022-09-17
```